# capistrano deploy with wrong version of Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

after I deploy with capistrano to a new server I see:

> /shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/

I don't even have ruby 1.9.1 installed on the server. and if i run: `ruby -v`
it returns 1.9.3 
but in all of capisrtano actions i keep seeing 1.9.1 
why is that? and how can i stop it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry. Ruby 1.9.1 to 1.9.3 is using that path by default. It doesn't necessarily mean you are using the wrong Ruby.

Comment: anyway i can know for sure?.. "rvm list" returns just ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Try `cap production shell` and run `ruby -v` there.

Comment: ok got "ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]"