# Changing rvm_ruby_version doesn't change the ruby version

Tags: rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano, capistrano3

In my deploy.rb I have `set :rvm_ruby_version, '1.9.3'`

In `../shared/bundle/ruby/` I see 1.9.1

Why is this not 1.9.3?

**Update**

I added ruby 1.9.3 to my gemfile.
I am seeing commands like this:

```
/home/rails/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby /home/rails/rails-capistrano/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets
```

Why go into `bundle/ruby/1.9.1`?

Comment: Why not enforce ruby version on gemfile? `ruby "1.9.3"`

Comment: Good idea. I made the change in the gemfile. Updating question.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822827/capistrano-deploy-with-wrong-version-of-ruby and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978797/how-do-i-configure-capistrano-to-use-my-rvm-version-of-ruby, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1.9.1` is a ruby compatibility version, this means that all 1.9.x rubies are supposed to be binary compatible